# Checking If A Sheet Exists In An External Closed Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I want to test whether certain sheets in the current workbook exist in another closed workbook and return a message saying which sheet/s are causing errors.

I prefer not to open/close the workbook so I'm trying to change the formula in a random cell to link to the workbook of filepath (fp) to test whether the sheet exists.

I've tested this with a dummy sheet that I know doesn't exist in the other workbook and it works but when I have more than one sheet that causes errors I get an "Application-defined or object-defined error". On the second iteration I believe the way the error handling is written causes the crash but I don't exactly understand how that works.

The code I've got is:

```
Sub SheetTest(ByVal fp As String)
Dim i, errcount As Integer
Dim errshts As String

For i = 2 To Sheets.Count
    On Error GoTo NoSheet
        Sheets(1).Range("A50").Formula = "='" & fp & Sheets(i).Name & "'!A1"
    GoTo NoError
NoSheet:
errshts = errshts & "'" & Sheets(i).Name & "', "
errcount = errcount + 1
NoError:
Next i

Sheets(1).Range("A50").ClearContents

If Not errshts = "" Then
    If errcount = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Sheet " & Left(errshts, Len(errshts) - 2) & " does not exist in the Output file. Please check the sheet name or select another Output file."
    Else
        MsgBox "Sheets " & Left(errshts, Len(errshts) - 2) & " do not exist in the Output file. Please check each sheet's name or select another Output file."
    End If
    End
End If

End Sub
```

Hopefully you guys can help me out here, thanks!

Comment: Interesting to see an example of you call this sub - what do you pass to the fp String? I was fairly sure that you couldn't access WorkSheet values if the Workbook was not open

Comment: The fp string contains the path of the external workbook with the [ ] brackets as you'd have in any typical linked cell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a slightly different approach:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim s As Worksheet

    For Each s In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        Debug.Print s.Name, HasSheet("C:\Users\blah\Desktop\", "temp.xlsm", s.Name)

    Next s


End Sub



Function HasSheet(fPath As String, fName As String, sheetName As String)

    Dim f As String

    f = "'" & fPath & "[" & fName & "]" & sheetName & "'!R1C1"

    HasSheet = Not IsError(Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(f))

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the speedy reply Tim!! This is indeed much more elegant and simple than what I had. I adapted the IsError(Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(f)) line in place of the error checker and it works perfectly.

Comment: FWIW Excel 4 macros are now disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for Tim's Function for error Handling:

VBA:

```
Function HasSheet(fPath As String, fName As String, sheetName As String)
On Error Resume Next
Dim f As String

f = "'" & fPath & "[" & fName & "]" & sheetName & "'!R1C1"

HasSheet = Not IsError(Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(f))
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    HasSheet = False
End If
On Error GoTo 0 
End Function
```

Answer (score -2):

Sub Tester()

MsgBox (Not IsError(Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("'C:\temp[temp.xlsm]Sheetxyz'!R1C1")))

End Sub

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide some explanation around the code you are providing.